# Run a project build as part of a Unit test?

Tags: java, maven, junit, integration-testing

I have a Java project in which I want to add a Unit test that `maven builds` a sample project (`shaded-jar`), runs this created jar and evaluates a written output file.

I am not sure if this is even possible from within a Unit test?

I experienced problems in the past when the unit tests were actually passing but once you created a shaded jar things break due to some dependency issues that seem to only occur in JAR files.
I looking for some `keywords` or even better an example how to do that or how to implement this kind of an integration test.

Comment: This is an integration test which can be handled using the maven-invoker-plugin which is primarily for running integration tests during maven plugin development but it can be used for other purposes as well. Or you can check the exec-maven-plugin which might help here as well...

Comment: Thanks, I took a look into it. I have now the step that a `sample` project is build, but I don't see how I can tell maven to actually execute this -jar file and passing parameters to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comment by @khmarbaise:

1. Add [maven-failsafe-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) to your build to execute integration tests:

   ```
   <plugin>
       <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.19.1</version>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <goals>
                   <goal>integration-test</goal>
                   <goal>verify</goal>
               </goals>
           </execution>
       </executions>
   </plugin>
   ```
2. Run your jar via [maven-exec-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/). For example:

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
       <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>1.5.0</version>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
               <goals>
                   <goal>exec</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                   <executable>java</executable>
                   <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}</workingDirectory>
                   <commandlineArgs>-jar ${project.build.finalName}.jar</commandlineArgs>
               </configuration>
           </execution>
       </executions>
   </plugin>
   ```
3. Run maven build at least up to `verify` phase, e.g.: `mvn clean verify`.

Important notes:

- Your jar probably doesn't return (doesn't fork into a separate process), so you'll need to use `async=true` too. Since `asyncDestroyOnShutdown` defaults to `true`, it should be stopped up automatically when build ends. If your jar forks, you should stop the forked process via your own manual stop command in post-integration-test phase.
- This is much easier with war or uber-jar (which include all dependencies within), because otherwise you need to add all dependencies on the classpath as well, which will take additional effort.
- If you're using something like [appassembler-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) which will handle classpath and startup, you can simply run the output of this plugin instead.